# Google App Maker - SuggestBox - Widget's datasource not in "loading" state

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm using SuggestBox with a Calculated Model. Options are provided by a database query. The Query Script (Server Script) is executed correctly and filtered records are returned, but the widget's datasource is not in "loading" state while queries are running; this makes using a spinner a little bit difficult. I have to use SuggestBox's events to make the spinner visible/not visible. Have I missed something?
If the Calculated Model has several datasources (I think it's possible) will SuggestBox use the one with the name equal to the Calculated Model's name?
Thank you.

Comment: I believe calculated models do have a loading state, although it may only apply when `datasource.load()` is called.  As for the datasource, suggest box uses whatever datasource it inherits.  So your suggest box probably uses one of your calculated model's datasources and whichever one you've set in the parent widget.  This could be the default datasource (which is named after the model it inherits) or it could be one that you explicitly define.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/images/model/DataSourceLifeCycle.png) image which leads me to believe that only the `load` function triggers `datasource.loading` and `datasource.loaded`.  To my understanding query filters are calculated and applied client side although this might be totally and completely incorrect and applying filters may very well change the loading state of a datasource.  I would suggest setting up a simple test which constantly outputs `datasource.loading` while changing query filters on calculated models to make sure.

Comment: Hi Rherma, thank you for your answers.
1) I've removed widget's datasource. Now my SuggestBox inherits no datasource at all. The parent panels have no datasource specified. And my SuggestBox continues working properly (I get suggestions). In "Suggest Box Query Options" section I had to specify a Model: I thought that SuggestBox could use the default (or the first) Datasource in that specified Model. 2) I think you're right about the load function.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the suggest box yet so I wasn't intimately familiar with how it pulls data.  Looks like you're correct though - you can either specify a model and in that case it uses all data and for calculated models uses either the first datasource or whatever datasource is named after that model (although I haven't tested this at all).  Like you said above you'll have to use events, etc to specify filters or otherwise modify the data it suggests on.

Comment: I add some details: I'm using a CUSTOM CLOUD SQL database and the server script specified in the model's "default" datasource runs a custom query (building and returning  an array of filtered records).

Comment: I just setup a quick test app with a suggest box and one calculated model with two datasources.  Each one has a different set of generated data.  The suggets box only pulls from the first one, ignoring any naming.

The suggest box then will only ever grab data from your custom query as long as it's the first datasource.  This may not be true for models that are not calculated, though, like in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and for testing.